# How to double and triple each number in a user-input integer?

Tags: python, string

In Python, how would I go about taking a user-input integer and double or triple each digit in the integer?

For example:

123 -> 112233
or
123 -> 111222333

Comment: If you had to solve this yourself, where would you start?

Comment: The logic of this should be pretty simple, right?  Why not give it a shot first and come back when you get stuck

Comment: the question is not as bad as the downvotes though. do you want result converted back to integer or leave as string?

Comment: `int(''.join(digit*3 for digit in str(n)))`  If `n` can be negative do `int(''.join(digit*3 if digit.isdigit() else digit for digit in str(n)))`

Answer (score 1):

The `*` operator between a string and an integer will produce the string N times. So you could break your input to characters, multiply each and re-join them:

```
result = "".join([x * 2 for x in str(user_inp)])
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Mureinik solution you could use `map` :

```
   def multiply(number, times):
       return ''.join(map(lambda x : x*times, str(number)))
```

Or depending on when you need to decide how to multiply you could end up with following functions:

```
  def digitMultiplierFor(number):
      def inner(times):
          return ''.join(map(lambda x : x*times, str(number)))
      return inner
```

Usage:

```
  multiplier = digitMultiplierFor(123)
  print multiplier(2) # output 112233
  print multiplier(3) # output 111222333
```

Or

```
  def digitMultiplierBy(times):
      def inner(number):
          return ''.join(map(lambda x : x*times, str(number)))
      return inner
```

Usage:

```
  multiplier = digitMultiplierBy(3)
  print multiplier(123) # output 111222333
  print multiplier(234) # output 222333444
```

If you need integer result just wrap string result with `int()`